# Why does VirtualBox want my attention every morning?

Tags: windows-vista, virtualbox

I'm running Vista 64-bit Ultimate on this PC.  On it, I've installed VirtualBox, and in that I'm running Linux.  Everything's working great.

I leave it running all the time.  When I come in in the morning, every time, the "Sun VirtualBox" item in the Windows taskbar is bright orange, like it's trying to get my attention.

What would cause this?  I'm curious both if somebody has an idea of something VirtualBox might do that warrants this attention-grab, or what to look for in the VB logs to find out what causes this.

I'm sure it's harmless, but I'd like to stop it if I can.

Comment: I've noticed this too.  Near as I can tell, it's caused by the guest OS changing state.  Perhaps sleeping or waking from sleep?

Comment: Me too, FreeBSD guest on Win XP 32-bit host.

Answer (score 2):

I have wondered the same thing, and the best I can determine is the the VirtualBox GUI has done something (like check for updates) that is triggering the notification on the taskbar. I wish I knew what it was specifically, but I don't know. Trolling around the [VirtualBox Forums](http://forums.virtualbox.org/) didn't seem to yield any indicators either.

What I can offer is the idea that you can start your VM "headless" and avoid the flashing icon entirely:

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm "name of vm"
```